# image rotation script

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick

So I have this script that will rotate images located in a directory, which works great.  However, it requires a refresh of the page in order to rotate the image.  Is there a way I can modify this to have it rotate the image when the image itself is clicked?
Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
<img src="rotate.php" alt="random image" />
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $folder = 'images/';

    $exts = 'jpg jpeg png gif';

    $files = array(); $i = -1;
    if ('' == $folder) $folder = './';

    $handle = opendir($folder);
    $exts = explode(' ', $exts);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        foreach($exts as $ext) {
            if (preg_match('/\.'.$ext.'$/i', $file, $test)) {
                $files[] = $file;
                ++$i;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $rand = mt_rand(0, $i);

    header('Location: '.$folder.$files[$rand]);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe use JavaScript as this is a client side problem.

Comment: So the PHP works fine? Just looking for a browser solution?

Comment: @Matt  Everything I posted works great.  I was just simply looking for a way to turn the image display into an onclick function so it could pull up another image from rotate.php when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: this is very basic but test it out and see if it works;

```
 <script>
  function changeImage(o){
   o.src = 'http://www.domain.com/testtest.php?' + (new Date()).getTime(); // time to help stop caching
    }
 </script>
 <img src="http://www.domain.com/testtest.php" onclick="changeImage(this)" />
```

and in your php add a content header to send the image eg if it is a `gif` or png...

```
 <?php
// see link at bottom for getting file extention

 switch ($selected_random_file_extention) {
  case "gif":
     header('Content-type: image/gif');
     $file_ext = "gif"; break;
   case "jpg":
     header('Content-type: image/jpg')
     $file_ext = "jpg"; break;
   case 3:
     header('Content-type: image/png');
     $file_ext = "png"; break;
  }

  //header('Content-type: image/gif'); // send as image 



   //$random_image_name = rand(1,5);

     // you would add $folder.$files[$rand]; and include you script above
     $random_image_name = $folder.$files[$rand]; 



                            // adjust paths as needed
       $img_file = "http://www.domain.com/".$random_image_name.".gif";
                                                               // .$file_ext;


   readfile($img_file);  // not sure how memory will go

    ?>
```

The idear is to set the `header` content type and to read and write the file to the output buffer using `readfile`, armed with this you could use ajax as another means to request the image and using the `status` to easly display a loading indicator.

If you where to Rewrite the URL you could change the extension of .php for the src or not even have an extention.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

using `pathinfo 'extension'` you can get the extention and then set the 
approprate `Content-type`

Comment: I've seen the java examples that list the images, however, there are over 20,000 images.  I could only image how slow that would turn out.

Comment: @syllable3, right thats a different matter then, are the image names in a predictable naming schema, like numbered?

Comment: negative. They are not predictable by any means.  Some include spacing, some include numbers, etc.

Comment: $syllable3  another way could be to use a URL REWRITE, can/do you have access to that on the server?

Comment: So would I need to append more header's for each image type? Example:      
`   
   <?php
   header('Content-type: image/gif'); // send as image 
   header('Content-type: image/jpg'); 
   header('Content-type: image/png');
`
...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function changeSrc(element) {
  var file_names = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"]; //etc
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * file_names.length);
  element.src = file_names[i];
}
</script>
<img src="image1.png" onclick="changeSrc(this)">
```

Just join your $files into a quoted comma separated string and insert that as the value for the file_names array above.

Comment: Which would work, if all the images were in the same naming format.  There are also over 20,000 images in the directory, which I could only assume would drastically slow down the process.

Comment: Would it be possible to change the var file_names to a directory, so that it would just rotate any image in that directory?

Comment: This would seem to be the right idea.

Basically, change the src attribute with JavaScript by appending a random number to the query string each time the link is clicked.

This refreshes the image and prevents caching.

<img src="rotate.php?1526321" alt="random image" />

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to his client side then I would add a link round your IMG tag and split your PHP script into two files.

```
<a href="rotate.php"><img src="random.php" alt="random image" /></a>
```

File 1 (rotate.php): Rotates the images

File 2 (random.php): Redirects to the random image

```
header('Location: '.$folder.$files[$rand]);
```

Comment: I tested this.  When the page is first loaded, the image is broken, and when clicked, it loads the actual image to the site. (ie, http://www.testsite.com/whateverimage.jpg)  So with that being done, the user can not click the image again to rotate to the next.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an IFRAME and then with javascript, refresh that frame randomly

Comment: What about browser image caching?

Comment: To improve this answer consider adding a sample code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into doing this with ajax?  This way you could trigger the PHP, then refresh the image, but not the rest of the page.

Comment: I have not.  Not very familiar with ajax.

Comment: Ajax is surprisingly simple if you don't mind using a framework like jQuery. (Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  

A similar option could be to use JavaScript to update the html in the div containing your image, removing the image tag and adding a new one.  (Though this might not consistently refresh the image.)