# Changing screens/pages with PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am building a food website that allows clients to build numerous customized menus that will display on a monitor in their establishment.  The site is built in PHP and now I'm challenged as to how to make the screens rotate.

There are 6 different screens to display, each containing images stored in the database. I need to run all six screens in succession after a pre-determined amount of time. I realize PHP alone will not do it, so I am using jQuery to assist. Flash is not an option.

The problem is jQuery needs to pull a Screen Id from the database which will allow the screens to change. Has anyone created this situation? I am stumped on the best way to make this work seamlessly.

Comment: You need to show us your code, HTML/CSS/JS, etc.

Comment: Which part of the situation are you stuck with? Either way, you want to look into Ajax for fetching the data "live"

Comment: Not necessarily, you can just rotate a fixed set of screens.

Comment: The part I'm stuck on is how to make the screens rotate. I have the first screen displayed using jquery. Once that screens is playing, what's the best way to make the screens advance? Just looking for suggestions, not code.

Comment: Look up a gallery script, which will preload the images and rotate through them. Use JS to refresh the page every so often incase the menu images change.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127483/image-rotation-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have JavaScript call back to the backend just to get the next ID in a fixed rotation, just send the info with the page. eg:

```
// assume URL formatted like: http://mymenu.com/page.php?n=13
$query = 'SELECT page_id FROM menu_pages WHERE menu_id = x ORDER BY [some condition]';
// code here runs query, creates array of page IDs, ie:
$ids = array(11,12,13,14,15,16);
$cur_id = intval($_GET['n']);

$next_index = array_search($cur_id, $ids) + 1;
$next_id = $ids[$next_index];

echo 'Cur: ' . $cur_id . ' Next: ' . $next_id;
// output: Cur: 13 Next: 14

$js_var = <<<_EOI_
<script type="text/javascript">
   var next_page = $next_id
</script>
_EOI_

// or without javascript at all

$meta_refresh = <<<_EOI_
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="30; url=http://mymenu.com/page.php?n=$next_id">
_EOI_
```